# Jclouds & Rackspace: API to schedule backup

Tags: java, backup, rackspace-cloud, jclouds

I would like to schedule backup of my instance, is there any service in API to do that?

ServerAdminApi has method createBackup which seems to cover my needs, but I can't retrieve this server from novaApi:

```
NovaApi novaApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("rackspace-cloudservers-uk")
                                .credentials(username, apiKey)
                                .buildApi(NovaApi.class);
Optional<? extends ServerAdminApi> wrapper = novaApi.getServerAdminExtensionForZone("LON");
ServerAdminApi serverAdminApi = wrapper.get(); 
//here exception because expected service isn't there
```

What can be wrong with it?

Or maybe I should leave API and use json to send commands like there, though it seems lots more complicated: 
http://docs.rackspace.com/rcbu/api/v1.0/rcbu-devguide/content/createConfig.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServerAdminApi is if you have your own OpenStack deployment that you have administrative privileges on. You won't be able to use ServerAdminApi with Rackspace.

You have the right idea that [Rackspace Cloud Backup](http://docs.rackspace.com/rcbu/api/v1.0/rcbu-devguide/content/overview.html) is the way to go. Unfortunately that API isn't supported in jclouds yet. I highly recommend adding a feature request for in our [JIRA issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS). In the issue, let us know what the minimum set of API calls is that would fulfill your requirements.

As you mentioned, to work around this for the time being you'll need to make calls directly to the API.

Comment: Thanks! So I implemented that using Rackspace Rest Api and it works. Unfortunately, I can't wait for JClouds new features... I see now to add monitoring checks I will also have to use Rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-404) if you would like to watch the progress of this provider.